# Dividing a group of paths in the middle

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I have traced and expanded a tire that I now want to cut straight in the middle so I can decrease the opacity of the left half. That group of paths the expansion created I can't cut now - even with a line where I want to cut an select cut objects below command. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Fabioo, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't actually 'cut' anything. Just use clipping masks:

- Draw a rectangle over half of your artwork, up to where you want the 'cut'
- Select All
- Object > Clipping Mask > Make
- Duplicate your masked artwork
- Edit your clipping mask on your duplicate to reveal the opposite half: Simply select the two outer anchor points of the mask and drag them to the opposite side of your masked artwork.

[image]

Comment: If I see it right, at the end of your insctructions I am left with two left halfs. One from the clipping mask and another one from the copied and subsequently edited clipping mask. Seems not to solve the problem.

Comment: No you're not left with two left halves. You don't flip or mirror anything you just edit *the clipping mask*, not the artwork, to reveal the opposite half of the duplicate.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see the drawing - must have misunderstood sth. I've done it now- except I don't see the opacity field when the square is selected and my shape is going down on the right side too, so I kinda  have to change the way I drag the duplicate to the right. Thanks though.